# How to calculate the standard deviation based on 5-minute OHLC bars?

Tags: std, dolphindb

The following is the part records of 5-minute OHLC bars. How can I obtain the Std of 5 previous records ( open, high, low, close) at each timestamp?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use higher-order function moving.

Please refer to https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Functionalprogramming/TemplateFunctions/moving.html for more information.

```
select *,moving(std, (fixedLengthArrayVector(close,high,low,open)),5) as std from t
```